# iphone: unable to copy instance of an array to other array

Tags: iphone, core-data

Dont why this is happening I have a method getOutage which returns an array of managed objects

```
NSArray *fetchedOutages = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
if (error) {
    NSLog(@"Error in Core Data: %@", [error description]);
}
return fetchedOutages;
```

when I try to copy this array to listOutage (this is a property)

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *listOutage
```

I tried to copy this array like this in didRowSelectMethod like this

```
if (listOutage) {
        NSLog(@"Its there");
        [listOutage release];
    }

    listOutage=[[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[self getOutage]];
```

I tried various other methods but all of then are failing.

This getoutage method returns 5 objects five objects got copied in listOutage but when I try to access the listOutage elements they are displayed as 'out of scope'
Please help me to overcome this I have to pass this to next ViewController.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when there is a property, use 'self.property' instead of 'property' that way, when somebody else reads your code it is more obvious if you mean an ivar or a property.

if you use self.property, you do not need to write

```
if (listOutage) {
        NSLog(@"Its there");
        [listOutage release];
    }

    listOutage=[[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[self getOutage]];
```

instead, just write

```
NSArray newListOutage=[[NSArray alloc]  initWithArray:[self getOutage]];
self.listOutage = newListOutage;
[newListOutage release];
```

the release and retain will be handled by the get/set method generated by the @synthesize property.